# Can anyone suggest a good alternative to Cs Music Player?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, music.app, third-party

When iOS 10 was released, I quickly realized that I didn't like that Apple removed the ability to clear the "Up Next" playlist in the native Music app.  I also wasn't a fan of its new appearance.  At first, I wasn't too concerned, as I was able to find a suitable third-party app, [Cs Music Player](http://www.csmusicplayer.com) (formerly known as Cesium), that included the feature to fully customize the queue of upcoming songs.  It also has a design aesthetic more similar to the Music app in iOS 9 than that of iOS 10 and later.

I was mostly happy with this app up until a few months ago, as it included the ability to edit the queue as well as some other nice features like the ability to change the theme color.  However, in a recent update, the developer of Cs Music Player decided to remove the custom queue management feature because it had been [causing performance issues](http://www.csmusicplayer.com/cesium5).  I had certainly noticed the performance issues, but I was a little disappointed that the feature was removed as a result.

So, I'm wondering if anyone can suggest an alternative to the native music app that is similar to Cs Music Player while also including the queue functionality.  This can be either a free or paid app (though preferably nothing more than $2 or $3).

[EDIT: I should note that what I'm looking for is an app built around MusicKit.]

Comment: That’s a bummer you’re not able to use the best alternative I know of. Cs player is my go to and I don’t really miss that feature. Hopefully the developer can bring it back - they surely know it was used and likely removed it if they had no better option. Your price point is going to be hard, I can’t imagine anyone having a business model for less than $10 a year to improve on Cs and Music the native app.

Comment: bmike, I still use Cs Music Player, since it seems to be the best third-party music player app that I can find.  Also, you're probably right - in the second link that I provided, the developer gives an explanation as to why he decided to remove the feature, and it seems like the performance issues were outweighing its usefulness.  I actually wonder if there is any MusicKit app that truly has custom queue management, since Cs' developer says that "Apple has never provided public access to the contents of the system queue."